# How can I apply clustering algorithm to my twitter dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I am still new to clustering. I have extracted a twitter dataset with many rows using tweepy:

Sample data:

| tweet | ID | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NSW Demons - Watch Melbourne v Sydney tonight | 1387339243786182657 | 2021-05-08 05:55:30 |
| Brown in and Harmes returns, Melb v Rich match | 1387332484715581440 | 2021-05-08 05:40:45 |
| Kick-off is at 7:10 PM from the Docklands. | 1385474911448096770 | 2021-05-08 05:35:21 |
| "RT @melbournefc: Kicking with Choco. | 1385474643541127168 | 2021-05-08 05:30:15 |

How can I apply a clustering algorithm to find clusters based on date and time . So that I can retrieve tweeting/retweeting activity every hour and generate a pattern.

For example:

if user tweets/retweets in between 1am - 2am then tweet/retweet is a part of cluster 1

if user tweets/retweets in between 2am - 3am then tweet/retweet is a part of cluster 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your rule is specific that every tweets between 1am -2am should be clustered together and so as tweets between 2am-3am. Then, no algorithm is needed here. You just use conditional assignment to assign clusters accordingly, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.Series(["2021-05-08 05:55:30", "2021-05-08 05:40:45", "2021-05-08 05:35:21", "2021-05-08 05:30:15"], name='date')
date = pd.to_datetime(date).to_frame()

# Assign cluster id accordingly
date['cluster'] = 0    # Default

# 1am - 2am
date.loc[(date['date'].dt.hour > 1) & (date['date'].dt.hour <= 2), 'cluster'] = 1

# 2am - 3am
date.loc[(date['date'].dt.hour > 2) & (date['date'].dt.hour <= 3), 'cluster'] = 2
```

Otherwise if you want to apply a clustering algorithm, for exmaple `kmeans`, to learn the cluster automatically to the date column, I suggest you to transform them into unix time stamp seconds, so they become numeric values and hence can be fed to a model:

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.Series(["2021-05-08 05:55:30", "2021-05-08 05:40:45", "2021-05-08 05:35:21", "2021-05-08 05:30:15"])

date_unix = (pd.to_datetime(date) - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta("1s")
print(date_unix)
```

outputs

```
0    1620453330
1    1620452445
2    1620452121
3    1620451815
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Then you apply `KMeans` clustering algorthm from `sklearn` to `date_unix`

```
from sklearn.cluser import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
```

here, n_clusters is a paramter that you can tune based on your knowedge.
And `np.expand_dims` turns the `3` sized array to a `3 x 1` matrix, since the model offten expects a matrix instead of a vector.
Then fit the model for your data:

```
km.fit(np.expand_dims(date_unix, axis=1))
```

then predict

```
cluster_id = km.predict(np.expand_dims(date_unix axis=1)
print(cluster_id)
```

outputs

```
[1 0 0 0]
```

you can see the algorithm clusters the first date into one cluster and the other three into another. Since the last three dates are closer to each other.